# Compare list item with a dictionary key and print out the value of the key if the item exists in the dictionary

Tags: python

Example code:

```
my_dict = {'ABC':'Apple','DEF':'Mango','GHI':'Pear','JKL':'Orange','MNO':'Plum'}
lst_x =  ['DEF','GHI']
```

Expected result:

```
['Mango', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a `list comprehension` to construct the requested list.
Essentially we iterate through the `list` in the outer loop, and through the `dictionary` in the inner loop and then we compare the `list` value with the `key`from the `dictionary`, and should we have a match, then we save the value of the associated `key` in the new output list.

This code snippet below works as described above:

```
my_dict = {'ABC':'Apple','DEF':'Mango','GHI':'Pear','JKL':'Orange','MNO':'Plum'}
lst_x = ['DEF','GHI']

out = [value for element in lst_x for key, value in my_dict.items() if element == key]
print(out)
```

When run it prints:

```
['Mango', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve multiple keys at once, by using `operator.itemgetter`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

my_dict = {'ABC':'Apple','DEF':'Mango','GHI':'Pear','JKL':'Orange','MNO':'Plum'}

lst_x = ['DEF','GHI']
# in case, if there's a chance, that lst_x would get some of the keys, that are not in my_dict - add the below line:
# lst_x=set(lst_x).intersection(set(my_dict.keys()))
res=itemgetter(*lst_x)(my_dict)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

('Mango', 'Pear')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple loop, ask if there is a key with the same value and print it, for example:

```py
my_dict = {'ABC':'Apple','DEF':'Mango','GHI':'Pear','JKL':'Orange','MNO':'Plum'}
lst = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO']

for key in lst:
    if key in my_dict.keys():
        print(key, '->' , my_dict[key])

>>> ABC -> Apple
>>> DEF -> Mango
>>> GHI -> Pear
>>> JKL -> Orange
>>> MNO -> Plum
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally don't believe in giving outright answers so I will give you a hint:

```
// for x in lst: 
//   if x in dictionary then
//     lst_x.append(x)
```

I believe that should be enough for you to figure out the rest.